# parentheses in defining a pointer C programming

Tags: c, parentheses

I am a newbie in C progrmming and I have looked at the following code:

```
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)Buffer;
```

What does the expression mean?

here is the link to the code http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/

Comment: It's called a cast ... any tutorial or reference on C will cover it. I strongly suggest that people actually read books about programming languages rather than trying to muddle along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It casts `buffer` to a pointer to `struct iphdr` and then initializes `iph` to that pointer. This is used because `buffer` is a pointer to a buffer of raw bytes, but in this function it is known that the bytes stored in the buffer follow the format of a `struct iphdr`. Hence the `struct iphdr` can be used to access the contents of the buffer, rather than having to interpret and manipulate the raw bytes.

**edit**: To clarify (as per comments): The cast does not copy or convert anything. It is basically just telling the compiler “I know that `buffer` is supposed to contain `unsigned char`s but at this particular time those bytes are actually a `struct iphdr` so let me access them through the pointer `iph` in a more convenient way”.

Comment: (I'm using the lowercase name `buffer` as per the original code linked from the question.)

Comment: This is how I understand what is happening, please tell me if I am wrong. 'buffer' is an array of unsigned chars and if first member of `iphdr` is for example an array of 3 unsigned chars then it would copy first 3 chars of buffer and the same would happen for further members of `iphdr`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is a pointer to a `unsigned char` array that is being used to storage the raw packet data.

This is recasting the type of `buffer` to be unsderstood as a pointer to `struct iphdr`, so you can assign it to `iph` and read it as a structure. Technically this is just supressing the compiler error that would say that the value of `buffer` cannot be assigned to `iph` because they are of different types, despite the fact they are both pointers.

Alternatively, you can make `buffer` of type `void*` instead.

A pointer to `void` can be assigned to any other pointer type without need to recast it's type:

```
void* buffer = malloc(65536);
...
void ProcessPacket(void* buffer, int size) {
    struct iphdr *iph = buffer;
    ...
}
```